# User test1 connected distant

Tags: linux

A few days ago I just typed `systemctl suspend` to standby my computer and it always work great but since ~2 days he return me that he can't hibernate because a user is connected in distant.
Then I type `ps aux | grep sshd` and it return me that a user `test1` is connected.
I already try to `sudo deluser test1` but it didn't resolve the issue. When I type `cat /etc/passwd` I can see a user `test1`.

What is this user ?

Second question, when I type `ps aux | grep sshd` it return me :

```
root sshd : /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
```

What is this ?

When I type `ps aux | grep [s]sh` output is :

```
root         825  0.0  0.0  12184  7020 ?        Ss   09:37   0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
leo         1493  0.0  0.0   6040   456 ?        Ss   09:38   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --session=ubuntu
```

Just this morning for example I can't use `systemctl suspend` because it return me that there is `User test1 is logged on sshd`

When I type `ps aux | grep [s]sh` output is :

```
root         887  0.0  0.0  12184  6680 ?        Ss   mars23   0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root       84544  0.0  0.0  13984  8908 ?        Ss   mars27   0:00 sshd: test1 [priv]
test1      84730  0.0  0.0  14120  6092 ?        S    mars27   0:00 sshd: test1
root       93721  0.0  0.0  13980  8912 ?        Ss   12:46   0:00 sshd: test1 [priv]
test1      93865  0.0  0.0  14116  5276 ?        S    12:46   0:00 sshd: test1
leo        96285  0.0  0.0  11608   736 pts/3    S+   12:48   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

Comment: The output of `ps aux | grep sshd` is showing you the [SSH daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_(Secure_Shell)), I'd say there is nothing strange in it. Though you should also see at least a `sshd` process for the remote user if it was connected. What is the complete output of `ps aux | grep [s]sh` (or `pgrep -a ssh`, if you have `pgrep`)?

Comment: root         825  0.0  0.0  12184  7020 ?        Ss   09:37   0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
leo         1493  0.0  0.0   6040   456 ?        Ss   09:38   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --session=ubuntu

Yeah right now test1 isn't connected, it happen mostly in the evening.

Comment: Is user `test1` known to you? I.e. didn't you add it to your system?

Comment: No, I have personally add 3 user : leo, lia, lio. And in /home there is only these 3 users.

Comment: The `deluser` command removes the definition of the user account from the system. It doesn't logout the corresponding user, though

Comment: @fra-san I just updated my post.

Comment: It's impossible to say whether your system has been compromised (i.e. `test1` is not a legitimate user, not created by you nor by a trusted person or a trusted piece of software). If it has, you can only stop using it as soon as you can and reinstall it from scratch, restoring your data from a backup copy.

Comment: To further inspect your issue: `sudo ss -ntp | grep ssh` to get the address of the remote ssh client and check if it's something you know/trust; `sudo -l -U test1` to check if `test1` can run commands as root (which would likely be a really bad thing); `journalctl -u systemd-logind` to see the history of the logins to your system (just in case it could tell you something).

Comment: This ip doesn't say me anything. Yeah I will reinstall Linux. Very strange, where can it come from ? Malaware ?

Comment: But user test1 can't run command as root, it's return me an IP from Russia haha well..